# Fail on Decode my json string :(

Tags: php, json

**how decode it with php**

```
$myjson = [{"type":"laser","material":"1","quantity":1000},
{"type":"motors","material":"1","quantity":1491477212},
{"type":"shield","material":"1","quantity":1491531189},
{"type":"hp","material":"1","quantity":1491531201}] ;
```

Comment: $json_data   = '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}';

$array_data = json_decode($json_data, TRUE);
print_r($array_data);

Answer (score 0):

check this code, you missed "'" in start and end "'". i have format it now you can use this code

```
<?php
$myjson = '[{"type":"laser","material":"1","quantity":1000},{"type":"motors","material":"1","quantity":1491477212},{"type":"shield","material":"1","quantity":1491531189},{"type":"hp","material":"1","quantity":1491531201}]' ;
$array = json_decode($myjson);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($array);
```